# jquery replace does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function calculateTotal( )
{
    var sum = 0;
    // iterate through each td based on class and add the values
    $( ".tdArticlePositionZeilensumme" ).each(function() {

        var value = $( this ).data( "amount" );
        //var value = "1,123.00";

        console.log( "Value before replace:" + value );

        var newValue = value.replace(/,/g,""); //
        console.log( "Value nach replace" );
        //sum += value;
        sum += parseFloat( newValue );
        console.log( "Zwischensumme: " + sum );
    });

    console.log( "Summe: " + sum);
}
```

I got the error: that value `doesn't have the function replace`. When I add the value manually like you see above, then the replace and the sum works.

But when I get the value from the data('amount'), then the variable value didn't have the replace-function.

I checked with console.log if an amount exists and yes, it exists.

I think when I get the amount and set it to the variable value, that value isn't a normal string variable.

Where is my error?

Comment: You're mixing numbers and strings, and only strings have a replace() method, either that or `data('amount')` doesn't return anytning, which is impossible for us to tell without more context.

Comment: it's a data, not jquery, try console.log(value) to see whether it's null or to see the object structure

Comment: Try `console.log( typeof value )` and see what you get ?

Comment: the type is number, i dont need to make a replace. So you are right, i have not a string, i have a number.

Comment: create a fiddle, that will be better?

Comment: the `data()` may return a type `Number`, without method `replace()` of course.

Comment: If it's of type number, there surely are no commas to replace, so just delete that line.

Comment: i have seen, that chrome most of the time get the typ number, but sometimes the same could be a string. In Firefox everything which is formated like 1,222.00 would be a string.

Comment: Now i check if the typeof value == "string" and then replace the "," and parseFloat(). And if it is a number then i use it direct

Answer (score -1):

The data(amount) has probably been set as a float. You can use `typeof(value)` to confirm the type of your variable.

Use `var newValue = value.toString().replace(/,/g,"");`

Comment: There is no `float` type in javascript, only `number`, and typeof is an operator, not a function, and if it's a number, there's no need to convert it to string to remove commas, numbers can't have commas.